# Calling factory from directives controller in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, factory

I am trying to learn Angular.js, I am using ng-boiler-plate to manage my test application.

However I have ran into a ptoblem and can't see the reason for it not working. Basically I am trying to inject a Factory and then call it from a directives controller.

However when I try to call it I get an error reporting the factory name (in this case dashboardFac) is undefined.

I will include the directive and factory below:

Directive:

```
angular.module( 'locationSelector', [
'ngBoilerplate.locationFactory'
] )

.directive( 'locationSelector', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    //template: '<h3>asdfasdfasd</h3>',
    templateUrl : 'components/locationSelector/locationSelector.tpl.html',
    link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {

        console.log("link working ");

        var $input = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#location' ) );

        $input.bind('focus', function() {
            console.log("stay focused son");
        });

    },
    controller: function($scope, dashboardFac, $element){
        $scope.locyTexy = "";
        $scope.api = dashboardFac;
        console.log($scope.api);
        $scope.change = function() {
            console.log("asdfasd");
            dashboardFac.assets.getLocations().then(function(result){  

            });
        };

    }
    };
})

;
```

Factory:

```
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate.locationFactory', [

  ]).factory('dashboardFac', function($http, $q){
    this.assets = {
      getLocations: function(args) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var parmUrl = "will be some url eventually";
      $http.jsonp({
          method: 'GET',
          url: parmUrl
      }).
      success(function(data, status) {
         deferred.resolve(data);
       }).
       error(function(data, status) {
         deferred.reject(data);
       });

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
});
```

Any help would be greatly apprieacted, I have a feeling I am missing something fundamental but hopefully someone can help point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A factory must return an object

Comment: is that a diffience between a factory and service ? As I had a service set up in a similar way that functioned correctly ?

Comment: hi this solved my problem you should have marked as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3):

You must inject `dashboardFac` factory to directive:

```
.directive( 'locationSelector', function(dashboardFac) {
[…]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to first inject the `factory` into your `directive`, as pointed out by Krzysztof Safjanowski

```
   .directive( 'locationSelector', function(dashboardFac) {
      […]
    })
```

Then your factory will have to return an Object, like every other factory:

```
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate.locationFactory', [])
  .factory('dashboardFac', function($http, $q){
    return {
      assets: {
        getLocations: function (args) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          var parmUrl = "will be some url eventually";
          $http.jsonp({
            method: 'GET',
            url: parmUrl
          }).
            success(function (data, status) {
              deferred.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function (data, status) {
              deferred.reject(data);
            });

          return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
    }
});
```